# Meteor Accounts Entry Facebook Authentication

Tags: dns, meteor, facebook-authentication

We are trying to set up a facebook authenication for our Meteor app using Accounts Entry package.

On facebook, we tried to set the Site URL to be http://something.to/ and also the URL http://www.something.to/

Case 1:
Facebook app setup: something.to
The browser url is www.something.to

When we try to login from the above browser url, we got the following error in the JavaScript browser console:

"Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "something.to" from accessing a frame with origin "www.something.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."

Case 2:
Facebook app setup: www.something.to
The browser url is www.something.to

When we try to login from the above browser url, we got the following error in the JavaScript browser console:

"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

We are hosting our app on modulus and the DNS is set up to point to something-12345.onmodulus.net using CNAME record. And the CNAME for www value is an alias of something.to

Not sure if it is a problem of our DNS set up or Accounts entry package. However, it works fine on something.meteor.com